# How do I check if a job is running on cluster using job name (CentOS)

Tags: process, gridengine

I am running a bash script to submit multiple jobs. The submission of a job only happens if such job is not already running. I want to use an if statement inside my bash script to simply check if "job123" is already running or in the queue.

I have tried different options with qstat and qstatus but I can't seem to check by job name. How can this information be retrieved? Also these outputs are just strings, I also did not have any luck using grep but I think there must be a specific command.

Comment: Is this with Sun Grid Engine or with some other job queuing system?

Comment: @Kusalananda I use qsub to submit jobs and qstat or qstatus to get info about jobs.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're using SGE. Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve with

qstat -r | grep -cw "jobname"

which gives a 0 or 1 which then I can use inside an if statement. It seems to me more of a hack than anything. The -r it's important because it displays full names of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Sun/Oracle Grid Engine's `qstat` utility only allows you to filter your jobs by user and job ID.  If you need to filter by job name, you will have to `grep` for it:

```
qstat -u $USER | grep -w jobname
```

For use in an `if`-statement:

```
if qstat -u $USER | grep -q -w "$jobname"; then
  # job is in the queue
else
  # job is not in the queue
fi
```

After a brief search on the web, I also found that [*some* versions of `qstat`](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qstat.html) *appears* to be able to filter by job name using the `-j` switch:

```
qstat -u $USER -j "$jobname"
```

I haven't been able to verify if this works or not. [Other versions](https://www.jlab.org/hpc/PBS/qstat.html) of this utility clearly can't do this (and doesn't even support `-u`).

Comment: Actually both of these have problems when the jobname is too long and not displayed entirely by qstat.